# ember.js tansitionTo and set property on the model

Tags: ember.js

What is the best way of handling the following scenario:

I have a route that handles creating new records of a certain type:

e.g.

```
App.ContactNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(controller){
        return App.Contact.createRecord();
    }
})
```

I want to be able to access this route by simply linking to it like this:

```
{{#linkTo contact.new}}New Contact{{/linkTo}}
```

The contact is a model that has a company property:

```
App.Contact = App.Person.extend({
    company: DS.belongsTo('App.Company'),
});
```

But I also want to be able to preset the contact to have this company set by default when creating a new contact as well as the default case were no defaults are specified.

How can I achieve this?  I could create a new route but then what is the best way to share the mark up?  Should I use a partial to share the common markup?

One way I thought was to create an action that would set the company property like this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
        contactFromCompany: function(company){
             this.modelFor('contactNew').set('company', company);
             this.transitionTo('contact.new');
        },
    },
```

But modelFor returns undefined if the model has not been set yet unless the route has been accessed previously and I am not sure if this is a great idea.

I have created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Zmt3/11/) that shows the problem.

I could create another route like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7Zmt3/16/) but neither situation is very nice.  Another solution is to override the setup method of the route that sets the context.

I think this is a reasonably common scenario and it would be nice to have a common way.